# Xcode deleted files location?

Tags: ios, xcode4, recovery

I accidentally deleted a .m file from Xcode. I didn't have version Control on and I only clicked the 'Delete' button. Is there any specific location it deletes to?
How could I get the file back?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you already checked the Trash and for some reason don't use Time Machine.

Comment: Time Machine... have saved my skin once or twice now, to good for not using it.

Comment: Also Dropbox w/packrat, its like Cloud Time machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that it is gone forever. Only delete references, or use version control.

Comment: +1 for using version control. There is absolutely no reason not to use it.

Comment: ...or at the very least, use the Snapshot feature. But definitely learn and embrace version control.

Comment: I wonder why they don't simply move the files to the trash. It seems to me that would be more inline with apple user-interface guidelines.